# Node js dependency for Angular 2.4.8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript

I am new for angular 2.4.8, I have gone through the angular site for tutorials and all, but everywhere I found that all angular libraries are imported using node modules (using package.json to install node js). Is it neccessary to use node js for angular 2.4.8 web application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can download and import dependencies manually. But if you are new. I highly recommend using angular-cli to start the project scaffold.